# wcf authentication kerberos with no ssl

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, kerberos

I have configured active directory.
Also I have several computers joined the domain.

I have wcf service hosted in IIS. The service uses wsHttpBinding.

I need to configure the wcf service and client to use windows authentication with kerberos.
Also I do not plan to use ssl.
(is kerberos part of active directory or I need to install it?)

Can someone suggest how to to that. Can this be done only with the config file, and without changing the code?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  Here's how to do it:

http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/01/wcf-security-wshttpbinding-with.html